# why "<ng-container> not working in "<tr>" tag

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ng-if

**Code:**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <ng-container ng-if="false"> // here ng-container not working
            <td>
            <ng-container ng-if="false">abc</ng-container>// here ng-container working fine
            </td>
            <td><ng-container ng-if="true">xyz</ng-container></td>
        </ng-container>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**OutPut:**

```
xyz
```

> here expected output is no one cell was display but in between `<tr>` and `<td>` tags `<ng-container ng-if="false">` are not working.

If anyone idea about this problem please get solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I analysis this issue in deep and i faced some situation like 
`<ng-container ng-if="">` or `<ng-container ng-show="">` or `<ng-container ng-hide="">` conditions not working between `<table>` and `<td>` tag but working inside `<td>` tag also `<ng-container ng-repeat="">` is working fine in above all criteria.

Answer (score 1):

Try to put ng-container before table row

```
<table>
    <ng-container ng-if="false">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <ng-container ng-if="false">abc</ng-container>// here ng-container working fine
            </td>
            <td>
                <ng-container ng-if="true">xyz</ng-container>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ng-container>
</table>
```