# AngularJS equivalent for Angular ng-container

Tags: angularjs, angular, angularjs-directive

Is here an AngularJS equivalent for Angular [ng-container](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#ngcontainer)?

Or should I create something myself with a transclude directive?

---

Example use cases:

1. Tables with interlaced pairs, triples etc. of cells:

   ```
   <table><tr>
     <ng-container ng-repeat="item in items">
       <td>{{ item.a }}</td>
       <td>{{ item.b }}</td>
     </ng-container>
   </tr></table>
   ```

   There should not be additional level in the DOM tree, and instead `<td>`s should be direct children of `<tr>` element.
2. There is similar problem with HTML lists, especially the definiton list where `<dt>` / `<dd>` elements should be direct children of `<dl>` while they usually exist in pairs.
3. Table-like arrangement of data with `display:grid`:

   ```
   <div style="display: grid; grid-template-columns: auto auto">
       <ng-container ng-repeat="item in items">
           <div>{{ item.a }}</div>
           <div>{{ item.b }}</div>
       </ng-container>
   </div>
   ```

   This case is even more problematic as the container element existing in DOM tree causes the whole layout to break, as it is rendered as the cell instead of its children.

Answer (score 26):

In cases you have mentioned, you can use `ng-repeat-start` and `ng-repeat-end` pair, respectively:

1. Tables with interlaced pairs, triples etc. of cells:

   ```
   <table><tr>
     <td ng-repeat-start="item in items">{{ item.a }}</td>
     <td ng-repeat-end>{{ item.b }}</td>
   </tr></table>
   ```
2. HTML lists:

   ```
   <dl>
     <dt ng-repeat-start="item in items">{{ item.term }}</dt>
     <dd ng-repeat-end>{{ item.definition }}</dd>
   </dl>
   ```
3. Table-like arrangement of data with display:grid:

   ```
   <div style="display: grid; grid-template-columns: auto auto">
     <div ng-repeat-start="item in items">{{ item.a }}</div>
     <div>{{ item.b }}</div>
     <div ng-repeat-end>{{ item.c }}</div>
   </div>
   ```

You can read about this in API reference: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat#special-repeat-start-and-end-points

Comment: the first solution (`ng-repeat-start` and `ng-repeat-end` ) was the best for me. thank you

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately in AngularJS `ng-repeat`, `ng-if`, etc must be used on an HTML element that will be present in the markup. Depending on the exact use-case you could try using an element directive with `replace: true`.

Comment: Could you provide some code example for use case where introduction of additional DOM tree level is forbidden due to HTML semantics, like in case of adding table cells or child nodes to some `display:grid` element?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the same [`ng-container`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43774482/why-ng-container-not-working-in-tr-tag) in both `Angularjs` and `Angular-2` as well.  But in `angular-2` have an  additional option  is  [`ng-template`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40529537/ng2-difference-between-ng-container-and-ng-template-tags) which is act as [`ng-container`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43774482/why-ng-container-not-working-in-tr-tag)

Comment: I use ng-container in AngularJS 1.6.3 and I see that the ng-container element is included in the DOM of the browser. Also, Webstorm says "Unknown HTML tag ng-container". So it is not working as expected in my project.

Comment: @mvermand You need to add the `angular-material.js` file as a Library in WebStorm:Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28701863/how-do-i-teach-webstorm-9-inspector-to-recognize-angular-material-design-tags-at

Comment: @RameshRajendran the original question had nothing to do with WebStorm. Could you please elaborate your answer?

Comment: this is not working for angularJs versions without any libs